# Background shift on mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw this wonderful effect at: http://www.dogstudio.be/

I was wondering how you replicate it? I am talking about the shifting of the image depending on the mouse moments, and the effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look here: [jQuery: Fullscreen "background" image that moves according to mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865005/jquery-fullscreen-background-image-that-moves-according-to-mouse-position)

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-image-panning/

http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/jquery-image-panning/demo/multiple-instances.html